# Modules + Fascade + Mediator combination in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, module, design-patterns, facade, mediator

I've finished reading a great article on http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/

This article explains how to combine modules, a facade, and a mediator together for a JavaScript application.

I can code what the article explains, but I don't understand why I need to use facade to access the mediator.

I think I can access the mediator directly from my modules.

Please advise me..

P.S: Is it a valid question here?

Comment: Do you know what is the difference or benefits between this mediator http://arguments.callee.info/2009/05/18/javascript-design-patterns--mediator/ and Addys mediator? For me it's not clear yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference material for that section, Pro Javascript Design Patterns, answers your question quite nicely when it says the following:

> Facades are never strictly necessary. The same tasks can be completed without them. This
>   is an organizational pattern; it allows you to modify the interfaces of classes and objects to be
>   more convenient to you.

Answer (score 0):

#### Building on Thedric Walker's answer...

Take this, perhaps ridiculous, analogy:

YOU are a woodpecker (module), and you would like to pick out some larvae (data) which have been lain on a house's support-structure (Core). Normally, you'd just peck (actually woodpeckers have a long, barbed tongue that wraps around their skull) the larvae off of the infrastructure, but some carpenter (Application Architect) has applied a Facade on the outside of the house. However, the carpenter was nice enough to *poke holes* in the Facade to allow *only woodpeckers* to access the larvae. Furthermore, the carpenter was smart enough to make these *holes* a certain shape -- allowing the woodpecker to accomplish more larvae-eating tasks per peck.

**So why have a facade, again?**

Relating the Facade back to Addy's post -- the Facade augments a *Sandbox* in that a sandbox provides predefined efficacies which allow one module to accomplish tasks in specific ways, e.g. wholesale. For instance, you wouldn't want a sandbox that forces the user to write:

`var node = getNode('#errorPanel');`
`node.innerHTML = 'Field is invalid!';`

A better sandbox may have something like:

`notifyUser.error('Field is invalid!');`

The *Facade* on the other hand, can provide those *throughways* just the same, by only listening to the `mediator.fire('error:Validation', 'Field is invalid!')` channel.

The Facade in Addy's post, which I use all the time, could theoretically simply forward requests onto the Core. Probably, it would check something in the channel's *signal* to make sure, say, a Finch isn't trying to peck larvae that will make it sick -- e.g. throw an Exception.

This is why *it may make sense to have a separate channel-medium (ie mediator) for your core, where your Facade is the sole 'referencer' to the Core -- and your modules only reference the Facade*. Another way, is to *enforce amongst your team* a convention for *discrete-channel-names*, e.g. `mediator.fire('ready://Core')` & `mediator.fire('updated://ToDos/task', taskId)`. The `facade` would listen to `'updated://ToDos/task'` and would make request(s) to the `core` -- which may look something like:

```
var thus = mediator.installTo(this);
this.on('updated://ToDos/task', function(id){
    thus.fire('request://Core/save/todo', id);
    thus.fire('user://Core/notify/task/added', id);
});
this.on('response://Core/save/todo', function(err, id){
    if(!err){
        // ... success -- notify module!
    } else {
        // ... notify for failure :(
    }
});
```

***ATTENTION!*** do *not* write your handlers directly within your listener calls!

I *really* hope this helps and that I don't get downvoted for talking about birds ;)